# RecyclerViews recycle view depending on viewType. Can RecyclerViews recycle depending on widget types

Tags: android

When I use RecyclerView , I usually create some ViewHolders depending on viewType. And I think this is the normal way that others do.

But can I recycle views depending on widget type? For example, I create some HashMaps to store TextView, ImageView and so on. When onCreateViewHolder is called, I get the needed widgets from the HashMaps. I think in some complex situations with many viewTypes, this method may be more efficient. Is this method feasible?

Comment: have you looked into getItemViewType() and getItem() functions, try overriding them and using your logic there

Comment: not yet. i am trying right now